# Compile and use glibc-2.13 from source for ubuntu x86_64 architecture

Tags: pthreads, glibc, nptl

I am trying to build a modified version of libc/NPTL. My ubuntu version shows that it is version 2.13. I want to create a separate libc/nptl/libpthreads and want to use it for an existing application (like apache) using dynamic loading without replacing existing glibc/libpthreads. I am new to kernel programming and dynamic loading. Can you provide an example of how to use libc/NPTL using dynamic loading capability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create a separate libc/nptl/libpthreads

That's easy: `./configure --prefix=/u && make && make install`. Congratulations, you now have a separate `libc/lipthreads` under `/u`

> and want to use it for an existing application (like apache)

It's not quite clear whether you want to use your new `libc` with existing (prebuilt) binary, or with one you can rebuild.

If the latter, simply add `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/u/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (for 64-bit binaries), and you are done.

If the former, *and* the application does not `execve` itself, you can invoke it like this: `/u/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /path/to/app`.

If the application does `exec` itself, or gets invoked by multitude of shell scripts which you don't want to modify, then you'll have to binary-patch the application: replace `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` string in the `.dynstr` section of the binary with `/u/lib64/ld-2.13.so` (new string has to be not longer than the old one).

> I am new to kernel programming

Your question has *nothing* whatsoever to do with kernel programming.